# discord.js dynamicaly add choices to options Slash Commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Making a lil' discord bot on my lost time
It's been a few hours I'm stuck now..

Basically, this is a part of my command help

Let's say I have an array categories like this :

```
let categories = [{name: "cat1", value: "cat1"},{name: "cat3", value: "cat3"},{name: "cat2", value: "cat2"}]
```

is there a way then to export them withoud having to write them all ?
something like this ?

```
module.exports = {
    data: new discord.SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("help")
        .setDescription("Display bot commands")
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName("category")
                .setDescription(`Categories showed in ${prefix}help`)
                .addChoices(categories)),
    start
};
```

I saw there was a method .setChoices but don't figured out how to use it since it does not accept arrays

I tried using .addChoices and .setChoices with no succeed
tried searching for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a way to fix my issue thanks to @Atomic Goblin
Still don't sure if it's the best solution right now, but it works

```
// CATEGORIES ARRAY
const categories = [
    {name:"commands", value:"commands"},
    {name:"weebpack", value:"weebpack"},
    {name:"games", value:"games"},
    {name:"bot", value:"bot"},
    {name:"config", value:"config"}
];
// NEW SLASH COMMAND BUILDER
let data = new discord.SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("help")
    .setDescription("Display bot commands");
// ADD NEW OPTION
data.addStringOption(option =>
    option.setName("category")
        .setDescription(`Categories showed in ${prefix}`));
// ADD CHOICES ON FIRST OPTION
categories.forEach(cat =>{
    data.options[0].addChoices(cat);
})
// EXPORTS DATA(slashcommandbuilder) AND START FUNCTION
module.exports = {
    data: data,
    start
};
```

Here I made an functional method, if it helps someone

```
// Dinamically add choices from json array
// Input :  discordSlashCommandBuilder()
//          optionName string
//          optionDesc string
//          choices array [{name: "name", value: "value"},{name: "name2", value: "value2"}]
//          isRequired ? boolean
// Return discordSlashCommandBuilder() with option
/**
 * 
 * @param {discord.SlashCommandBuilder} slashCommand 
 * @param {String} optionName
 * @param {String} optionDesc
 * @param {Array} aChoices
 * @param {Boolean} isRequired 
 * @returns 
 */
function slashCommandAddOptionWithChoices(slashCommand, optionName, optionDesc, aChoices, isRequired){
    // get current index
    let idx = slashCommand.options.length;
    // Create new option
    slashCommand.addStringOption(option =>
        option.setName(optionName)
            .setDescription(optionDesc)
            .setRequired(isRequired));
    // Add choices to last option
    // stop after 25 entries (max choices limit)
    let i = 0;
    aChoices.forEach(choice =>{
        if(i === 25) return;
        slashCommand.options[idx].addChoices(choice);
        i++;
    });
    return slashCommand;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try breaking this into a function, then you can iterate through the commands. I think the file would look something like this:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");

//Note you could instead pass categories into this function
const fetchMySlashCommandsFunction = () => {
  const categories = [
    { name: "cat1", value: "cat1" },
    { name: "cat3", value: "cat3" },
    { name: "cat2", value: "cat2" },
  ];
```

const helpBuilder = new discord.SlashCommandBuilder().setName("help")
.setDescription("Display bot commands")

```
  categories.foreach(cat => {
     helpBuilder.addStringOption((cat.name) =>
          // not sure where prefix is defined in your code?
          .setDescription(`Categories showed in ${prefix}help`)
          .addChoices(cat.name)
      );
  });

  return data;
};
export default fetchMySlashCommandsFunction;
```

To retrieve data from this function it would be `const data = fetchMySlashCommandsFunction()`

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping
I tried using your code but didn't succeed to

It blocks on the second/third line of your second block, "," expected it says
Also replaced .foreach by .forEach

Plus the stringOption has to be unique, the string option would be a string "Category", and in this option would be choices like "Games", "Fun", "config", ... something like that in practice : https://ibb.co/4frgC05

Comment: Okay, just found out how to dit by using your idea, thanks ! Gonna edit my question to post the solution

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Might be re-opening this a bit late, just wanted to contribute with a probably easier to deal with it :

```js
.addChoices(...categories))
```